# How can I store one-hot-encodings as an object?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, categorical-data

First, some background on my model's architecture.

The inputs to my keras the model are fairly simple:

- Categorical variable A
- Categorical variable B
- Numerical input C, on the range [0,1].

The model features a single output:

- a number on the [0,1]

When training the model, my input data is a dataframe sourced from an SQL database using `pd.read_sql()`. I one-hot-encode the categorical variables A  and B (which are in `col1` adn `col2` of the dataframe `original_data`, respectively) with the following function:

```
from keras import utils as np_utils

def preprocess_categorical_features(self):
        col1 = np_utils.to_categorical(np.copy(self.original_data.CURRENT_RTIF.values))
        col2 = np_utils.to_categorical(np.copy(self.original_data.NEXT_RTIF.values))
        cat_input_data = np.append(col1,col2,axis=1)
        return cat_input_data
```

Later on, when I need to make predictions from this model, input data comes from a live feed from RabbitMQ in the form of a dictionary. This RabbitMQ data has to be processed by it's own (different) `reprocess_categorical_features()` function.

This brings me to my question: How can I ensure that the one-hot-encodings are exactly the same, whether I'm preprocessing data from the database, or a rabbitMQ feed?

The One-Hot Encoding for A applied to the database data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          | One-Hot-Encoding |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "coconut"     |      <0,1,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "apple"       |      <1,0,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "quince"      |      <0,0,0,1>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "plum"        |      <0,1,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The One-Hot Encoding for A applied to the RabbitMQ data (they have to be the same):

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          | One-Hot-Encoding |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "coconut"     |      <0,1,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "apple"       |      <1,0,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "quince"      |      <0,0,0,1>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "plum"        |      <0,1,0,0>   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is there a way for me to save the encodings as a dataframe, numpy ndarray, or dictionary, so that I could pass the encodings from the function that pre-processes my training data, to the function that pre-processes my input data? I'm open to using other libraries than Keras for OHE, but I'm interested to know if there's a way to accomplish this using keras' [to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) function I'm currently using.

Comment: also please post expected dataframe

Comment: @anky_91 Hey thanks! I'm not really expecting a data frame; the function I wrote above takes a dataframe as input (through `self.original_data`, but returns `cat_input_data`, which is a numpy ndarray.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how I can store the mapping of categorical values to one-hot-encoded vectors used by keras' `utils.to_categorical()` function, so that I can use this mapping for later pre-processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on keras' [`utils.to_categorical`](https://keras.io/utils/) method, I decided to use [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). This allowed me to declare a one-hot-encoder object, `self.encoder` when dealing with the training data:

```py
class TrainingData:
    def preprocess_categorical_features(self):
        # declare OneHotEncoder object to save for later
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

        # fit encoder to data
        self.encoder.fit(self.original_data.CURRENT_RTIF.values.reshape(-1,1))

        # perform one-hot-encoding on columns 1 and 2 of the training data
        col1 = self.encoder.transform(self.original_data.CURRENT_RTIF.values.reshape(-1,1))
        col2 = self.encoder.transform(self.original_data.NEXT_RTIF.values.reshape(-1,1))

        # return on-hot-encoded data as a numpy ndarray
        cat_input_data = np.append(col1,col2,axis=1)
        return cat_input_data
```

Later on, I could re-use that encoder (by passing it as an argument, `training_data_ohe_encoder`) to the method that processes the input data needed to finally make my predictions.

```py
class LiveData:
    def preprocess_categorical_features(self, training_data_ohe_encoder):
        # notice the training_data_ohe_encoder parameter; this is the 
        # encoder attribute from the Training Data Class.

        # one-hot-encode the live data using the training_data_ohe_encoder encoder
        col1 = training_data_ohe_encoder.transform(np.copy(self.preprocessed_data.CURRENT_RTIF.values).reshape(-1, 1))
        col2 = training_data_ohe_encoder.transform(np.copy(self.preprocessed_data.NEXT_RTIF.values).reshape(-1, 1))

        # return on-hot-encoded data as a numpy ndarray
        cat_input_data = np.append(col1,col2,axis=1)
        return cat_input_data
```